# How vertical-align:middle and overflow:hidden will work in a single div?

Tags: html

I am using div, in that i need to align text vertically and need to hide text based on height whatever i am giving. Below code i am using, but overflow-hidden is not working.

```
<div>
    <div style="width:100px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;height:5px;">
            Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email?
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put your code between code tags so it can be seen by those who want to help you.

Comment: @Jules When you see something like that, you should edit it, it will be peer reviewed by us (people with high enough reputation to edit) and it will be accepted and changed.

Comment: @Truth: Good point, never considered I could do it myself... :P Tnx!